# Diazonium ion positive charge

Tags: organic-chemistry, nitro-compounds

I am confused about the nature of the positive charge on the nitrogen atom in the diazonium ion. Where does it come from? That nitrogen atom has 4 bonds, but I cannot deduce whether one of them is dative, because the other nitrogen forms 3 normal bonds, and the carbon in the aromatic ring has no empty orbitals or lone pair of electrons. So how does that nitrogen form 4 bonds and how does it have a positive charge? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a diazonium, or rather any compound  where nitrogen forms four bonds, the nitrogen has a positive formal charge.

The reason is simple, nitrogen used it's lone pair of electrons to make the fourth bond. This gives nitrogen a positive charge.

A more simple example is the ammonium ion. While ammonia has 3 bonds and 1 lone pair, the ammonium ion has 4 bonds, the lone pair from ammonia was shared with a proton to make the ammonium ion.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't read much about the concept of formal charges so I'll have a look at any page about it.

Comment: @FahdAl-Seba'ey Sure thing. If you think my answer is satisfactory, click the accept button. This lets everyone know you are satisfied and you got the answer you needed.

Comment: Note that formal positive is not the real positive. The entire species is positive, but the real positive charge is delocalized over the whole thing.